# How to replace GIMP image in existing layer

Tags: electron, progressive-web-apps, wrapper, gimp

I'm new to GIMP.I'm using Electron-PWA-Wrapper with Visual Studio to wrap a website into Microsoft app.

In the Electron-PWA-Wrapper,I need to replace Tray- and App-Icons into src/assets.

Following is the screenshot:

[image]

My question is how to replace the default red image to my own image.

I have tried many ways,but failed.

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if it's actually about using GIMP than it's not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes,I know,sorry about that.I really have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: Are you trying to edit some image file? If so, what format is it?

Comment: What is a "Microsoft app"?

Comment: Why are you using Gimp? Can't you just replace the icon files?